# How do I close two open jquery.reveal.js modal box one by one?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a link. If I click this link, first modal box will open. And there is a link in this box. If I click the seccond link new box will open. The problem is that: If I click close button of the seccond box it will close. But then I couldn't close the first one. What can I do? Please help me!!!

```
<div id="first_box" class="reveal-modal">
            <div class="inner_content">
                <h1>Title1</h1>
                <p>some content</p>
                <a href="link to the seccond box">
            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="seccond_box" class="reveal-modal">
            <div class="inner_content">
                <h1>Title2</h1>
                <p>Some caontent.</p>
            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the js code and relevant js libraries.

Comment: usually logic is in the models/controllers

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, calling the trigger `reveal:close` closing the first modal when closing the second

```
<div id="first_box" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <h1>Title1</h1>
        <p>some content</p>
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="seccond_box">Open the second modal</a>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">X</a>
</div>
<div id="seccond_box" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <h1>Title2</h1>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal" onclick="closeOne();">X</a>
</div>


<a href="#" data-reveal-id="first_box">Click to open the first modal</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closeOne(){
    $("#first_box").trigger('reveal:close');
}
</script>
```

You can use the following library with modifications to close all.

https://github.com/rkgarcia/reveal